# Is there a way I can concatenate two of my YouTube videos from within YouTube?

Tags: youtube, concatenation

My gimbal today went wrong while recording, and while fixing it, I accidentally pressed stop on my camera.  Thus, I have two YouTube videos ([1](https://youtu.be/9zg7e0D6m1E) and [2](https://youtu.be/Z70Pc_Rea6k)).  If straightforward, I'd like to concatenate them from within YouTube.

I know how to use video editing software on my computer to make a new video, but these are just videos of me practicing Chinese, so they're not majorly important and I'm not keen in juggling large video files just to fix this problem (it can take hours to compile, and uploading videos to YouTube from China requires a VPN which has monthly limits, etc.).  I'm wondering if there's a simple way to do this from within YouTube.

**Question**: Is there a way I can concatenate two of my YouTube videos from within YouTube?

I asked [Sage](https://poe.com/Sage) and it said: "As of 2021, there is no official video editing feature within YouTube itself that allows you to concatenate two of your own YouTube videos."  I'm not sure if this is accurate, but it's likely if it were possible in some easy way, Sage would point it out.

It may just be easiest to leave things as they are.